# Calibre + Mathematica?

Tags: formatting

The latest version of [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) converts doc.x files (with hyperlinked tables of contents built to Smashwords specifications) to beautiful epubs in a matter of seconds. Calibre even flows text around tables. Hooray! Math and science nerds are now closer to self published authors than ever before! Unfortunately, Calibre does not recognize the code native to Mathematica. Calibre puts a large question mark wherever you have a Mathematica derived equation, symbol (bar chart) and or a slider bar driven demonstration. What to do? Does anyone know of a work around?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about using _Mathematica_ or any of the other Wolfram Research software for which questions are accepted on this site.

Comment: This question is about integrating Mathematica into epubs. Not Relevant? DuH!

Comment: It's not that this is a bad question, but that this site is not where you should be asking it.

Comment: Maybe you could add more details of your work-flow with *Mathematica* and *Calibre*. Do you pass a notebook file to *Calibre*, or do you try to embed *Mathematica* expressions in other files (.docx?)? Then question could be reworded to something like "How to export *Mathematica* formulas/plots/... to *insert formats supported by Calibre*?"

Comment: It seems [*Calibre* internally uses some form of HTML-based representation](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html#introduction). It's definitely possible to export *Mathematica* expressions to HTML-embedable assets. Depending on *Calibre* capabilities, details of exported expression and your preferences, it might be [SVG](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/SVG.html), [MathML](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MathML.html) or [raster image format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RasterImageFormats.html).